# stop performseguewithidentifier once executed

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ibeacon

I have this code to update distance using beacons.

```
func updateDistance(distance: CLProximity) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8) {
        switch distance {
        case .Unknown:
            print("unknown")
        case .Far:
            print("far")
        case .Near:
            print("near")
        case .Immediate:
             print("Immediate")
             self.performSegueWithIdentifier("beaconSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

I would just like to ask if how to stop the self.performSegueWithIdentifier function once its already executed.

Comment: You shouldn't stop self.performSegueWithIdentifier. Only call it if you need to.

Comment: I do understand however  in this example when the beacon constantly emits "Immediate" location it will perform the segue. Is there a better way of doing a segue aside from this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you do not want self.performSegueWithIdentifier to execute, simply don't call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a flag when you first perform the segue.  Like this:

```
var seguePerformed = false

func updateDistance(distance: CLProximity) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8) {
        switch distance {
        case .Unknown:
            print("unknown")
        case .Far:
            print("far")
        case .Near:
            print("near")
        case .Immediate:
             print("Immediate")
             if !self.seguePerformed {
                 self.seguePerformed = true
                 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("beaconSegue", sender: self)
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This one worked just right. however when back is pressed from the view and I try to put the beacon near the app again, it prints immediate and does not open the segue anymore.

Comment: Simply add a method definition of `func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)` and inside the method, reset `seguePerformed=false`

Comment: Thank you very much that did the job. Thanks a lot. Have a very good day. Now I can move on the project.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the `performSegueWithIdentifier`, you can do like this:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String,sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if ... { // Set the condition if you want it can be perform
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```